# Understanding Gunicorn Sync Workers working for handling multiple requests

Tags: gunicorn

I am using Sync Workers of Gunicorn with 4 workers running.. 
Lets say 100 request hit the server at same time..
How does gunicorn handle this, Does all 4 workers have 25 requests each
Or master worker maintains the queue and sends the requests to child worker based on their availability ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Benoitc(main contributor in Gunicorn):

The worker doesn't maintain any queue. Everything arrive in the backlog of the listener, the system balance the connection to the processes that wait on accept.

Comment: This response isn't clear. As OP asks, say all requests take the same time to complete, would each worker process receive 25 requests?